Scope overlap of identically-named entities belonging to the same name space
From C23 &sect'6.2.1(4):

Every other identifier has scope determined by the placement of its declaration (in a declarator or type specifier). If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears outside of any block or list of parameters, the identifier has file scope, which terminates at the end of the translation unit. If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the associated block. If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears within the list of parameter declarations in a function prototype (not part of a function definition), the identifier has function prototype scope, which terminates at the end of the function declarator. If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will end strictly before the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). Within the inner scope, the identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope' the entity declared in the outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.

I am unsure about the restriction in bold. It seems to have been introduced in the technical corrigendum for C1X as a fix for defect report 345, but I am still not clear as to why it is needed. Doesn't it follow automatically from the language syntax combined with the rules for scope termination that are mentioned just before this sentence?
For example, in the example provided in the defect report, parameter f has block scope and function f has file scope. According to the rules for scope termination, this means that parameter f's scope terminates at the end of the block that represents function f's body, whereas function f's scope terminates at the end of the enclosing translation unit. Since the language grammar ensures that the block that represents function f's body is fully contained within the translation unit, doesn't it follow that parameter f's scope ends before that of function f? If so, isn't the restriction in bold redundant?

It looks to me like the sentence you bolded is essentially descriptive, to aid the comprehension of the reader, and not prescriptive, intended to be a specification of how scopes must be implemented.

Re “doesn't it follow that parameter f's scope ends before that of function f?”: Does it? Given a translation unit ending in void f(int f) { /*…*/ }, do the scopes of both f’s end at the final }? Or would you consider the function’s identifier to extend “one beyond” the last token in the translation unit, even though there is no following token?

Thanks @EricPostpischil. Re “even though there is no following token” - wouldn't there be some sort of end-of-file marker? So I would consider parameter f's scope to end at the final }, and function f's scope to end at the EOF marker that immediately follows the } (assuming there is no newline character after the}). I know that it is undefined behaviour for a non-empty source file to not end in a newline character, but I am not really sure how translation units are otherwise formatted and parsed.

There's generally no harm to repeat the syntax rules in the semantics part of the normative text. This part of the standard has evidently been muddy historically: looks like the text in both 6.2.1 (scope) and 6.9.1 (function definitions) has changed multiple times between C89 all the way to C23.
